# Android fastboot build failure due to incorrect Java version

Tags: java, android, makefile, java-6, fastboot

I'm trying to compile fastboot for Android using [this guide](http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html), but I'm getting the following error:

```
************************************************************
You are attempting to build with the incorrect version
of java.

Your version is: java version "1.6.0_23".
The correct version is: Java SE 1.6.

Please follow the machine setup instructions at
    http://source.android.com/source/download.html
************************************************************
```

Note that I have the correct *major* version, but not the correct *minor* version. Is the Android makefile really this picky? Is there a way that I can use Java 1.6.0 when trying to compile the source code instead of this revision? Do I have to uninstall Java to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AH. Shortly after posting I discovered this guide for [Ubuntu 32-bit users](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI-Android-GingerBread-2.3-DevKit-1.0_DeveloperGuide#For_Ubuntu_on_32-bit_machines) (why I couldn't find it in the hour leading up to the question, I don't know...). I now have fastboot working. Just thought I'd leave this info here in case someone else encounters this problem. :)